# Why do I need to upload my file twice to get it in the DB?

Tags: angular, typescript

So basically i am working on a file-upload that accepts .csv and stores it in localStorage (no server, local solution) - everything is working fine but I always need to upload a file twice to get it in my localStorage, sometimes it´s working the first time and sometimes not.

Also a weird thing is when I router to a different location and upload the file everything works, the problem only appears when I am in my "Overview" - where the data will be displayed.

my template:

```
  <input type="file" #csvReader name="Upload CSV" id="txtFileUpload" 
  (change)="uploadListener($event)" accept=".csv" class="inputfile" />

  NEW FILE

  </label>
```

and my TS:

```
  uploadListener($event: any):void {  

    this._dataService.initializeDB($event);

  }
```

data.service.ts:

```
 initializeDB($event: any){

  this.students = [];
  localStorage.removeItem('students');

        let files = $event.srcElement.files;  

  if (this.isValidCSVFile(files[0])) {  

    let input = $event.target;  
    let reader = new FileReader();  
    reader.readAsText(input.files[0],'ISO-8859-1');  

    reader.onload = () => {  
      
      let csvData = reader.result;  
      
      let csvRecordsArray = (<string>csvData).split(/\r\n|\n/);  

      let headersRow = this.getHeaderArray(csvRecordsArray);  

      this.getDataRecordsArrayFromCSVFile(csvRecordsArray, headersRow.length);  
    };  

 
}
```

Comment: Did you try using the `loadend` event instead of `onload`.

Comment: yea nothing changed, still need to double upload

Comment: Which part of the code was not executed always, input change event or FileReader onload event

Comment: the FileReader onload event will not execute always